# Tabulator: Horizontal Scrolling not working

Tags: tabulator, sveltekit

As far as i understand Tabulator will automatically insert a horizontal scrollbar, if the rows doesn't fit the table width.

This is my Tabulator Component:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import {
    Tabulator,
    PageModule,
    ReactiveDataModule,
    ResponsiveLayoutModule,
    ResizeTableModule
} from 'tabulator-tables';
import type { ColumnDefinition } from 'tabulator-tables';
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

export let data: any[], columns: ColumnDefinition[];

let tableComponent: HTMLElement;

onMount(() => {
    Tabulator.registerModule([
        PageModule,
        ReactiveDataModule,
        ResponsiveLayoutModule,
        ResizeTableModule
    ]);
    new Tabulator(tableComponent, {
        data: data, //link data to table
        columns: columns, //define table columns,
        height: '500px',
        pagination: true,
        paginationSizeSelector: [10, 25, 30], //enable page size select element with these options
        responsiveLayout: true,
        reactiveData: true
    });
});
</script>

<div bind:this="{tableComponent}"></div>

<svelte:head>
    <link
        href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.9.1/dist/css/tabulator.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" />
</svelte:head>
```

I have also tried it without responsiveLayout: false and renderHorizontal: 'virtual'.

Even if i enclose the Tabulator in a div with overflow-x: scroll nothing happens.
The horizontal scrollbar doesnt appear and only the content which fits on the screen is displayed.

The content expands, if i enlarge my Browser window.

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/5be4cdc48a694be793d5e4a0bdbd0f15?version=3.52.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of the responsive module is that it dynamically hides cells.

The main problem is probably that you are using an outdated stylesheet (note the version: `tabulator-tables@4.9.1`). You should not be referencing `unpkg.com` for anything that is not purely demonstrational anyway.

With Vite you can just import the CSS directly from the package:

```html
<script>
    import 'tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css';
    // ...
```

You can also import it from the `<style>`:

```html
<style>
    @import 'tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css';
</style>
```

(Vite will probably even automatically inline this.)

Without `responsiveLayout` it should scroll horizontally by default.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. I recreated the scenario: https://svelte.dev/repl/5be4cdc48a694be793d5e4a0bdbd0f15?version=3.52.0

Comment: Did you remove the `responsiveLayout` option? Because that will just remove columns if they do not fit.

Comment: The REPL includes the script twice, you should remove the `<script>` from `<svelte:head>`, and as mentioned, you can't have `responsiveLayout` and scrolling at the same time.

Comment: For the REPL you also might have to wait for the stylesheet to load, as the style is not inlined and apparently layout calculations can get messed up otherwise. See [this fixed example](https://svelte.dev/repl/efa1b4e9f3a14c768c9962614e943486?version=3.52.0).

Comment: Thanks so much! It was late and i read with responsiveLayout it should scroll...